# UIViewController in a UITabBarViewController reset when app logs out

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a UITabBarController with three tabs, each is a UIViewController with a UITableView. 
I have a logout button and I want to clear out the UITableView in all of these UIViewController, so from one of the UIViewController I did:

```
NSArray * viewControllers = ((UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController).viewControllers;
AllGroupsViewController * agvc = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
[agvc.groups removeAllObjects];
[agvc.table reloadData];
SearchViewController * svc = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
[svc.results removeAllObjects];
[svc.table reloadData];
```

However, it seems that the NSArray of viewControllers is empty. Is there another way to reset everything again when you logout?

The problem with my current app is that when I have a user who is logged in and uses the app. The he logs out and a new user logs in, that new user can still see the prior user history in the UITableView.. this is why I want to clear this out when a user logs out, across the three UIViewController in the UITabBarController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you check the value of self.parentViewController? I am not sure if it returns the tab bar controller.

Instead of self.parentViewController.viewControllers, do

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers
```

Comment: I think this should work.. now the issue is that the three UIViewController in the tab bar is inside the UINavigationController.. so how do I access the UIViewController of a UINavigatioNController

Comment: UINavigationController has two properties that could help you. rootViewController and visibleViewController. visibleViewController will give you the one on screen, and rootViewController will give you the bottommost one. Here is a link to the UINavigationController documentation.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: check by giving this [tabBarViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]

Answer (score 0):

Define that array in AppDelegate and during Application Start create TabController with Table View through Code.

Now with your logout button set the datalist or source of tableview to nil;

Comment: when I logout I am just presenting a ModalView of the login page.. I am not sure how this can be executed in the app delegate

Comment: Do you know how to implement Delegate Methods ? 

You can define a delegate method in your LoginViewController and implement in your root view controller that once LogOut Calls happens before loginscreen displays it clear the table view data source to nil;

Comment: Yes I do have a few delegates.. I was going to use this method initially. but since the logout button is actually shown from one of the UIViewController that is in the UITabBarController, so the delegate goes there instead of the RootViewController

Comment: You can define a method in Application Delegate such as ClearContents and accessing AppDelegate you can call up that method from any click button.